# Consuming multiple messages from two different queue using @StreamListener in RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices

I have two queue which are able to produce messages in the RabbitMQ queue. Now I want to consume this messages from a same consumer service based upon the action.One queue was created when user add some item and other was created when user try to delete from the UI.
I can able to consume one messages using @StreamListener but how to consume both the messages using @StreamListener?

in Consumer class:

```
    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
        public void processRegisterAdd(String message) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
            System.out.println("for adding item message in queue: " + message);

        }


 /* @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
            public void processRegisterDelete(String message) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
                System.out.println("for deleting item message in queue: " + message);

            }*/
```

in Consumer application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=itemRetrival
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=itemRetrivalQueue
```

How do I consuming both the messages depending upon the action in Consumer class using @StreamListener.